# Cypress Cucumber common folder not working

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I'm new to cucumber for Cypress and I can't seem to get step definition files in my common folder to be used. My tests work if all of my steps are in the file which the feature file links to but if I put any of the steps in my "commonSteps.js" file that's inside my integration/common folder then the test fails saying that it can't find a step definition for the common step. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding the commonPath to the package.json and that doesn't work either.
nonGlobalStepDefinitions is also set to true.

[Image of file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7BjO.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in your cypress-cucumber-preprocessor in package.json, without seeing it's hard to say exactly what the problem is.

You can find here a guide to what different combinations of settings lead to. https://dev.to/jankaritech/e2e-testing-with-cypress-03-cypress-cucumber-gherkin-integration-350j

I think it should be

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {     
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
  "commonPath": "integration/common",
  "stepDefinitions": "integration"
}
```

Also, just a hint, if cypress runner is already running and you change something on the package.json, you need to restart the cypress runner to see what your changes result in, it's not enough to just restart a test case in the runner.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your folder structure is not defined properly in the config file. Here the steps you need to consider in order to run cypress-cucumber test successfully.

1. First, folder and file names should be same like `common` => `common.js` and same name for feature file too, such as `common.feature`.
2. Then you need to define the folder structure in the `package.json` file and also set your `nonGlobalStepDefinitions` to `false`.

   "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
   "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
   "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/common"
   },
3. Now, save and re-run your test. Hopefully this time it should work.